# Some questions about the prime factors of a very fast growing function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, factorial, big-numbers

Let $$f(n)=\sum_{j=1}^n (j!)^{j!}$$ for integer $n\ge 1$

The first few values are $f(1)=1 , f(2)=5 , f(3)=46661 , f(4)=1333735776850284124449081472890437$

- Is $f(n)$ a prime number for any $n>2$ ?

The smallest prime factors of $f(n)$ for $n=3,\cdots, 13$ , except $n=10$ are

```
3  29
4  7
5  41
6  241
7  43
8  3593
9  17
11  61
12  13
13  13
```

For $n\ge 12$ , $13$ is a prime factor, so the last possible prime number is $f(10)$. It has $$23\ 804\ 069$$ digits.I found no prime factor upto $3\cdot 10^{10}$ (doublecheck would be fine!). $f(10)$ is prime with probability about $1$ to $1$ million, but a prime factor would be very welcome !

- Are the $f(n)$ squarefree except $f(21$) ?

The only non-squarefree case I found so far is $$83^2\mid f(21)$$
Is there any other pair $(n,p)$ with prime $p$ and $p^2\mid f(n)$ ?

- Is $f(n)$ a semiprime for any $n>3$ ? The next possible case (apart from $f(10)$) is $n=34$ (which is almost surely NO semiprime) and for $n\ge 72$ , we have $13\cdot 73\mid f(n)$ so a semiprime is not possible anymore.
- The complete factorization of $f(5)$ would be very welome.[here](http://factordb.com/index.php?id=1100000003950911251) is the partial factorization. The remaining composite has $193$ digits.

Comment: This is https://oeis.org/A165711