# Is $S_n=1!^{1!}+2!^{2!}+3!^{3!}+\cdots+n!^{n!}$ a perfect power if $n\geq2$

Tags: number-theory, perfect-powers

Is $S_n=1!^{1!}+2!^{2!}+3!^{3!}+\cdots+n!^{n!}$ a perfect power when $n\geq2$?

I know that:

- $S_n\equiv2\pmod{3}$ if $n\geq2$, so $1!^{1!}+2!^{2!}+3!^{3!}+\cdots+n!^{n!}$ is never a perfect square if $n\geq2$.
- $S_n\equiv5\pmod{9}$ if $n\geq2$, so it is not a perfect cube if $n\geq2$.
- The last 2 digits of $S_n$ is $37$ if $n\geq5$, so $S_n$ cannot be a perfect 5th power, since $37$ is not a 5th power residue $\pmod{100}$.

But can $S_n$ be a higher odd prime perfect power?

Comment: It's a bit hard to test this by computer given the magnitude of the number. $n=6$ has $2058$ digits.

Comment: If $n\geq 5$ it ends in $1333735776850284124449081472890437$.

Comment: There is no perfect power for $n\geq 12$ as $S_n\equiv 0\pmod {13}$ and $S_n\equiv 117 \pmod{13^2}$. So we need to "only" check $n\leq 11$.

Comment: By the same method I have found such prime for all $n\leq 11$ as well, except for $n=10$, yet.... I guess $S_{10}$ has large prime factors.

Comment: $S_3=6^6+2^2+1=46661=29 \times 1609$. $S_4, S_5,$ and $S_6$ have small prime factors. I don't see any reason to suspect any higher number value will be a perfect power.

Comment: @Sil Does that mean that $S_{10}$ is the only case we have to verify ?

Comment: I can confirm with brute force that there is no perfect power for $n \le 9$. I currently search a prime factor of $S_{10}$ to solve this case as well.

Comment: $S_{10}$ is not a perfect power. I have however not found a prime factor yet.

Comment: $S_{11}$ is divisible by $61$ , but not by $61^2$ , hence not a perfect power.

Comment: Considering Sil's comment , the only possible prime except $S_2$ is $S_{10}$. For the other $n$ , we have a small prime factor.

Comment: @Peter Yea, $S_{10}$ seems to be the only tricky case, my alg ran over night and find it has no prime factor $p\leq 7489247851$.

Comment: @Sil My computer only arrived at $1.6\cdot 10^9$ although I applied an improved trial division. Neverhteless , $S_{10}$ should be composite.

Comment: The number is around $2^{79075402}$, so finding large factors might take a long time. Alternative search could try to find $m$ such that $m^k=S_{10}$ for $k=2,3,\dots,79075402$. For each such $k$, this can be done by halving the intervals for example, I haven't had a chance to program this though. However you wrote that "$S_{10}$ is not a perfect power", how did you find this?

Comment: PARI/GP can check huge numbers whether they are a perfect power without factoring them. It took a while , but it returned after some minutes "$0$".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147926/discussion-between-sil-and-peter).

Comment: [related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4575682/82961)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per Sil's comment

> There is no perfect power for $n\geq 12$ as $S_n\equiv 0\pmod {13}$ and $S_n\equiv 117 \pmod{13^2}$. So we need to "only" check $n\leq 11$.

it is sufficient to check $n \leq 11$. One can find small prime factors $p$ for $2 \leq n \leq 9$ and $n=11$ with the property that $p^2$ does not divide $S_n$. A direct PARI/GP computation for the case $n=10$ shows that $S_{10}$ is not square. Thus we can conclude that there is no perfect power for $n\ge 2$, and a possible prime (other than $S_2=5$) occurs only for $n=10$.

Comment: I checked $S_{10}$ for a perfect power , not just for a perfect square !